# center 3 items on 2 lines

Tags: html, css

In fact, I would like to center my 6 items of this way below:

[image]

My problem is that I center my items on a line instead of center my elements on 2 lines.

In grid CSS, there is a solution, but I want to avoid this way because I am beginner.

On css-tricks, I don't find of example?!

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#background

If you have an idea, I am interested.

Thank you

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }


  
/*******************************/
/********* Service CSS *********/
/*******************************/

.service {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.service .section-header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.service .flex-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.service .service-item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  transition: .3s;
}

.service-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.service .service-item:hover,
.service .service-item.active {
    background: #343148;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.service .service-icon {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.service .service-icon i {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #343148;
  z-index: 3;
}

.service .service-icon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: pulse-border 2000ms ease-out infinite;
}

.service .service-icon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 200ms;
}

.service .service-item h3 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: .3s;
}

.service .service-item:hover h3,
.service .service-item.active h3 {
  color: #F7CAC9;
}

.service .service-item p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Service Start -->
        <div class="service">
           <div class="section-header">
             <p>What we do</p>
             <h2>Yoga For Health</h2>
            </div>
             <div class="flex-container">
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Heal emotions</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item active">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Body Refreshes</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Mind & Serenity</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Enjoy Your life</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Body & Spirituality</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Body & Mind</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div> 
        </div>
        <!-- Service End -->
```

Comment: Why not use grid? Honestly I would put flex and grid right next to each other in terms of complication. Grid is pretty simple once you dig into it and it is very powerful when it comes to layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use display grid? When the carpenters used to use hammers to nail a nail into a board, the nail gun came out...  ***Grid is a row/column css NAILGUN!***
This is the kind of layout display grid was made for and grid layout works splendidly in conjunction with **flex**, why not use all the tools you have at your disposal?

With grid you can change the `grid-template-areas` layout to move an element in the layout without touching the HTML! ***Pneumatic powered nail gun!***

Consider that the following lines of CSS are all I added and/or changed to get the layout to work as a two row, three column layout. Along with the css I also added unique classes (***one***, ***two***, ***three***, ***four***, ***five***  and ***six***) to each grid child item for use in `grid-area` and `grid-template-areas`

```css
/* Changed this from flex to grid */

.service .flex-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr, 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr, 1fr, 1fr;
  /* Grid can be very literal in its layout when using 
     grid-template-areas:
   rows  1fr  each |   column-1 | column-2 | column-3 
  ------------------------------------------------
     Row1 -->      |   el-one   | el-two   | el-three      
     Row2 -->      |   el-four  | el-five  | el-six    
                       ^^^          ^^^        ^^^
                       1fr          1fr        1fr               */
  grid-template-areas:
        /* col1 col2 col3 */
  /*row 1*/"one two three" 
  /*row 2*/"four five six";
  padding: 2rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}


/* add grid-areas for each unique selector to identify its grid-area */

.one {
  grid-area: one;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}

.five {
  grid-area: five;
}

.six {
  grid-area: six;
}

/* removed the :not(last-of-child) margin as it is no longer needed */
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*******************************/


/********* Service CSS *********/


/*******************************/


/* Added flex display here with a flex-direction of column
   centered justification and items alignment */

.service {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.service .section-header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Changed this from flex to grid */

.flex-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr, 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr, 1fr, 1fr;
  /* Grid can be very literal in its layout when using 
     grid-template-areas see below
   rows  1fr  each |   column-1 | column-2 | column-3 
  ------------------------------------------------
     Row1 -->      |   el-one   | el-two   | el-three      
     Row2 -->      |   el-four  | el-five  | el-six    
                       ^^^          ^^^        ^^^
                       1fr          1fr        1fr               */
  grid-template-areas: 
    "one two three" 
     "four five six";
  padding: 2rem;
  gap: 16px;
  /* width: 80vw; <-- if you want more padding on your container */
}


/* add grid-areas for each unique selector to identify its grid-area */

.one {
  grid-area: one;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}

.five {
  grid-area: five;
}

.six {
  grid-area: six;
}


/* removed :not(last-child) as it is no longer needed */

.service .service-item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  transition: .3s;
}

.service .service-item:hover,
.service .service-item.active {
  background: #343148;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.service .service-icon {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.service .service-icon i {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #343148;
  z-index: 3;
}

.service .service-icon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: pulse-border 2000ms ease-out infinite;
}

.service .service-icon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 200ms;
}

.service .service-item h3 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: .3s;
}

.service .service-item:hover h3,
.service .service-item.active h3 {
  color: #F7CAC9;
}

.service .service-item p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Service Start -->
<div class="service">
  <div class="section-header">
    <p>What we do</p>
    <h2>Yoga For Health</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <!--/ Added unique selector "one" here for use in grid-template-areas 
                      on parent and on own element for grid-area /-->
    <div class="service-item one">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
      </div>
      <h3>Heal emotions</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/ Added unique selector "two" here for use in grid-template-areas 
                      on parent and on own element for grid-area /-->
    <div class="service-item active two">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
      </div>
      <h3>Body Refreshes</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/ Added unique selector "three" here for use in grid-template-areas 
                      on parent and on own element for grid-area /-->
    <div class="service-item three">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
      </div>
      <h3>Mind & Serenity</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/ Added unique selector "four" here for use in grid-template-areas 
                      on parent and on own element for grid-area /-->
    <div class="service-item four">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
      </div>
      <h3>Enjoy Your life</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/ Added unique selector "five" here for use in grid-template-areas 
                      on parent and on own element for grid-area /-->
    <div class="service-item five">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
      </div>
      <h3>Body & Spirituality</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/ Added unique selector "six" here for use in grid-template-areas 
                      on parent and on own element for grid-area /-->
    <div class="service-item six">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
      </div>
      <h3>Body & Mind</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Service End -->
```

**Grid layout power:** Without actually touching the HTML we can re-order our `grid-area` elements in our `grid-template-areas` css property and they will change to those literal positions in the layout:

```css
      grid-template-areas:
        "six five four" 
        "three two one";
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*******************************/


/********* Service CSS *********/


/*******************************/


/* Added flex display here with a flex-direction of column
   centered justification and items alignment */

.service {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.service .section-header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Changed this from flex to grid */

.flex-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr, 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr, 1fr, 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "six five four" 
    "three two one";
  padding: 2rem;
  gap: 16px;
  /* width: 80vw; <-- if you want more padding on your container */ 
}


/* add grid-areas for each unique selector to identify its grid-area */

.one {
  grid-area: one;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}

.five {
  grid-area: five;
}

.six {
  grid-area: six;
}


/* removed :not(last-child) as it is no longer needed */

.service .service-item {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  transition: .3s;
}

.service .service-item:hover,
.service .service-item.active {
  background: #343148;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.service .service-icon {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.service .service-icon i {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #343148;
  z-index: 3;
}

.service .service-icon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: pulse-border 2000ms ease-out infinite;
}

.service .service-icon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 200ms;
}

.service .service-item h3 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: .3s;
}

.service .service-item:hover h3,
.service .service-item.active h3 {
  color: #F7CAC9;
}

.service .service-item p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Service Start -->
<div class="service">
  <div class="section-header">
    <p>What we do</p>
    <h2>Yoga For Health</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <!--/ Added unique selector "one" here for use in grid-template-areas 
                      on parent and on own element for grid-area /-->
    <div class="service-item one">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
      </div>
      <h3>Heal emotions</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/ Added unique selector "two" here for use in grid-template-areas 
                      on parent and on own element for grid-area /-->
    <div class="service-item active two">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
      </div>
      <h3>Body Refreshes</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/ Added unique selector "three" here for use in grid-template-areas 
                      on parent and on own element for grid-area /-->
    <div class="service-item three">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
      </div>
      <h3>Mind & Serenity</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/ Added unique selector "four" here for use in grid-template-areas 
                      on parent and on own element for grid-area /-->
    <div class="service-item four">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
      </div>
      <h3>Enjoy Your life</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/ Added unique selector "five" here for use in grid-template-areas 
                      on parent and on own element for grid-area /-->
    <div class="service-item five">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
      </div>
      <h3>Body & Spirituality</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
      </p>
    </div>
    <!--/ Added unique selector "six" here for use in grid-template-areas 
                      on parent and on own element for grid-area /-->
    <div class="service-item six">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
      </div>
      <h3>Body & Mind</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Service End -->
```

Answer (score 2):

The property you are looking for is called flex-wrap. I made some changes to your snippet, take a look.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }


  
/*******************************/
/********* Service CSS *********/
/*******************************/

.service {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.service .section-header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.service .flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.service .service-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  transition: .3s;
}

.service .service-item:hover,
.service .service-item.active {
    background: #343148;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.service .service-icon {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.service .service-icon i {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #343148;
  z-index: 3;
}

.service .service-icon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: pulse-border 2000ms ease-out infinite;
}

.service .service-icon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 200ms;
}

.service .service-item h3 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: .3s;
}

.service .service-item:hover h3,
.service .service-item.active h3 {
  color: #F7CAC9;
}

.service .service-item p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Service Start -->
        <div class="service">
           <div class="section-header">
             <p>What we do</p>
             <h2>Yoga For Health</h2>
            </div>
             <div class="flex-container">
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Heal emotions</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item active">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Body Refreshes</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Mind & Serenity</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Enjoy Your life</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Body & Spirituality</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Body & Mind</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div> 
        </div>
        <!-- Service End -->
```

Answer (score 2):

This might probably not the best way, but it works:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }


  
/*******************************/
/********* Service CSS *********/
/*******************************/

.service {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.service .section-header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.service .flex-container {    
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    width: 80vw;
    left: 10vw;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.service .service-item {
  text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
    transition: .3s;
    flex: 0 0 calc(33.333% - (20px * 2 / 3));
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.service-item:nth-child(n+4) {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.service .service-item:hover,
.service .service-item.active {
    background: #343148;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.service .service-icon {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.service .service-icon i {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #343148;
  z-index: 3;
}

.service .service-icon:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: pulse-border 2000ms ease-out infinite;
}

.service .service-icon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #F7CAC9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 200ms;
}

.service .service-item h3 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: .3s;
}

.service .service-item:hover h3,
.service .service-item.active h3 {
  color: #F7CAC9;
}

.service .service-item p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Service Start -->
        <div class="service">
           <div class="section-header">
             <p>What we do</p>
             <h2>Yoga For Health</h2>
            </div>
             <div class="flex-container">
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Heal emotions</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item active">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Body Refreshes</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Mind & Serenity</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Enjoy Your life</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Body & Spirituality</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="service-item">
                  <div class="service-icon">
                    <i class="flaticon-workout"></i>
                  </div>
                  <h3>Body & Mind</h3>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div> 
        </div>
        <!-- Service End -->
```